# Calling success, error callbacks using subscribe in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

It is giving *responce.json* () is not a function for my case.

#### File *component.ts*

```
this.AuthService.loginAuth(this.data).subscribe(function(response) {
  console.log("Success Response" + response)
},
  function(error) {
  console.log("Error happened" + error)
},
  function() {
  console.log("the subscription is completed")
});
```

#### File *AuthService.ts*

```
loginAuth(data): Observable<any> {
  return this.request('POST', 'http://192.168.2.122/bapi/public/api/auth/login', data,{ headers:this. headers })
      .map(response => response)
      //...errors if any
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Giving [object,objet]

If I use a map function service, like .map(response => response.json()), it is giving an error like responce.json () is not function.

Comment: Re *"responce.json"*: Not *"[response](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/response#Noun).json"*?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using this structure:

```
this.AuthService.loginAuth(this.data).subscribe(
    suc => {
        console.log(suc);
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Also you might want to stringify your data being sent to the server, such as:

```
loginAuth(data) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var info = JSON.stringify(data);

    return this._http.request("http://192.168.2.122/bapi/public/api/auth/login", info, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
}
```

And you must declare a variable in the constructor of your service referencing Http like such:

```
import { Http, Headers, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
}
```

This is the way it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your service page

```
//Import if needed

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';    
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
return this.http.post('http://192.168.2.122/bapi/public/api/auth/login', data, options)
.map((res: Response) => {
    return { "res": res.json() };
})
.catch((e: any) => {
    console.log(e.status);
    return Observable.throw({"Errors":e.json()});
});
```

And your template ts file

```
this.AuthService.loginAuth(this.data).subscribe((result: any) => {
    let res = result.res;
    console.log(res)
},(error: any) => {
    if(typeof error['Errors'] !="undefined"){
        console.log(error['Errors']);
    }
});
```

It's working for me perfectly

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change and ***why***? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42203672/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).